# Hibernate in Gradle

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, jar, gradle

I'm just learning to setup a Hibernate-Gradle Project and my Directory Structure is as follows.

[image]

TestHibernateInsertion.java is the Entry point of Application and it has the below source to place value in my localDB.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {

          Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure   ("../../../resources/org/gradle/hibernate.cfg.xml");

          ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();

          SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
          Session session = sf.openSession();
          Person p = new Person(2132);
          session.persist(p);
          Transaction transact = session.beginTransaction();
          transact.commit();
          session.close();
          System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

Gradle build it successfully but when I execute the jar build by Gradle I get.
[image]
And When I export the whole project as runnable jar from eclipse, I get different error being thrown.
[image]

1. Curious to know why the error being thrown varies on when we build the jar with different technics and also how to correct the error.
2. When executing the jar provided by running gradle build command on my project, the error I get and I interpret it as the no class entry being defined but i have already defined in my build.gradle file as

   jar {
       manifest {
           attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.gradle.TestHibernateInsertion' 
       }
   }
3. And the error on executing the  exported runnable jar from Eclipse, it looks to be the relative path error but i have no clue of solving it (used getResource() method as well.) How do we refer the xml files at resource folder from main source code file with relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems with what you did.

The first one is an understanding problem of how Java libraries work. When you compile a program and generate a jar file, with libraries as dependencies, the compiler only checks that you're using the classes and methods from the libraries correctly, and the produced jar file doesn't contain all the code from the libraries. All the jar file contains is your own classes and resources. So you still need to have the libraries, at runtime, in the classpath. This means that your command line to start your app should look like

```
java -cp lib/myjar.jar;lib/hibernate.jar;lib/javassist.jar;... org.gradle.TestHibernateInsertion
```

All the libraries your code depends on, and the libraries on which the libraries depend, etc. (recursively) need to be in the classpath.

If you create an executable jar file, then the jar file's manifest must contain a classpath entry listing the relative path to all the jar files needed by the jar file.

The second mistake you're doing is that you assume that the `configure()` method takes a relative path to a file. It doesn't. What it takes is a path to a resource from the classpath. This resource path is used by the ClassLoader to load the resource. So the path should look like `"org/gradle/hibernate.cfg.xml"`.

Finally, unless you're contributing to the gradle project, you shouldn't use the package `org.gradle`. Use the domain name of your own company, association or whatever.

Comment: Nixet : Thx. U really made me Understand certain things. Thx again